# Chaining two functions () -> Task<A> and A->Task<B>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I don't know if I am thinking in the wrong way about TPL, but I have difficulty understanding how to obtain the following:

I have two functions

```
Task<A> getA() { ... }
Task<B> getB(A a) { ... }
```

This seems to occur often: I can asyncronously get an A. And given an A, I can asynchronously get a B.

I can't figure out the correct way to chain these functions together in TPL.

Here is one attempt:

```
Task<B> Combined()
{
    Task<A> ta = getA();
    Task<Task<B>> ttb = ta.ContinueWith(a => getB(a.Result));
    return ttb.ContinueWith(x => x.Result.Result);
}
```

The `ContinueWith` is where I get confused. The returned type is a "double-Task", `Task<Task<B>>`. This somehow just seems wrong to me.

**UPDATE 2011-09-30:**

By coincidence I found the extension method `TaskExtensions.Unwrap` that operates on a `Task<Task<T>>` to give a `Task<T>`.
So until we get C# 5.0, I can do ta.ContinueWith(a=>...).UnWrap() in situations like this where the continuation itself returns a task.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does your `getB` *have* to be a method which returns `Task<B>` rather than `B`?

The problem is that [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989582.aspx) is:

```
public Task<TNewResult> ContinueWith<TNewResult>(
    Func<Task<TResult>, TNewResult> continuationFunction,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
)
```

So in your case, because `getB` returns `Task<B>`, you're passing in a `Func<Task<A>, Task<B>>`, so `TNewResult` is `Task<B>`.

If you can change `getB` to just return a `B` given an `A`, that would work... or you could use:

```
return ta.ContinueWith(a => getB(a.Result).Result);
```

Then the lambda expression will be of type, `Func<Task<A>, B>` so `ContinueWith` will return a `Task<B>`.

EDIT: In C# 5 you could easily write:

```
public async Task<B> CombinedAsync()
{
    A a = await getA();
    B b = await getB(a);
    return b;
}
```

... so it's "just" a matter of working out what that ends up as. I *suspect* it's something like this, but with error handling:

```
public Task<B> CombinedAsync()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<B> source = new TaskCompletionSource();
    getA().ContinueWith(taskA => {
        A a = taskA.Result;
        Task<B> taskB = getB(a);
        taskB.ContinueWith(t => source.SetResult(t.Result));
    });
    return source.Task;
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: `getB` doesn't _have_ to return a `Task<B>`, it is just convenient because it represents an asynchronous operation.
The problem with `getB(a).Result` is that it will block a thread as soon as the `Task<A>` has completed, so this doesn't scale well in an application where I have thousands of A's and B's.

Comment: @BjarkeEbert: Right. It's possible that using a `TaskCompletionSource` would help here. It does feel like the kind of thing that *should* be easy (and actually is with async in C# 5, so I should be able to backport the thinking, as it were...)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I really look forward to C# 5 (in my current project it is not an option) - things are really easier that way.
I think the `TaskCompletionSource` method is usable when being non-blocking really matters, and one could even make a generic combinator for combining getA and getB.

Comment: Also, my colleague pointed me to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884470/task-chaining-without-taskcompletionsource that seems very related.

Comment: See also the Then in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx

Answer (score 6):

In case you are familiar with LINQ (and the Monad concept behind it), then below is a simple Task monad which will allow you to compose the Tasks.

**Monad implementation:**

```
public static class TaskMonad
    {
        public static Task<T> ToTask<T>(this T t)
        {
            return new Task<T>(() => t);
        }

        public static Task<U> SelectMany<T, U>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, Task<U>> f)
        {
            return new Task<U>(() =>
            {
                task.Start();
                var t = task.Result;
                var ut = f(t);
                ut.Start();
                return ut.Result;
            });
        }

        public static Task<V> SelectMany<T, U, V>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, Task<U>> f, Func<T, U, V> c)
        {
            return new Task<V>(() =>
            {
                task.Start();
                var t = task.Result;
                var ut = f(t);
                ut.Start();
                var utr = ut.Result;
                return c(t, utr);
            });            
        }
    }
```

**Usage example:**

```
        public static void Main(string[] arg)
        {
            var result = from a in getA()
                         from b in getB(a)
                         select b;
            result.Start();
            Console.Write(result.Result);
        }
```

Comment: Wow, I had not thought in that direction at all, but it looks very interesting!
Actually I have a little bit of background in Haskell, so when I wrote getA and getB, the composability reminded me of monads, but I didn't see the connection to LINQ.
And I am a bit surprised that it is possible to make such a generic extension method ( `ToTask<T>(this T)` ):)

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer would probably work

```
Task<B> Combined()
{
    Task<A> ta = getA();
    Task<B> ttb = ta.ContinueWith(a => getB(a.Result)).Unwrap();
    return ttb;
}
```

Is a much more elegant way to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are unable to use `await`, you can certainly use `Unwrap`, but it handles exceptions sub-optimally. The method I prefer is `Then` as described in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx). Composition becomes simple and elegant:

```
Task<B> Combined()
{
  return getA().Then(getB);
}
```

For those interested in the details, I wrote a [blog post](http://ruudvanasseldonk.com/2013/05/01/the-task-monad-in-csharp) a while ago about exactly this problem of composing asynchronous methods, and how monads provide an elegant solution.