# Chaining `Task<T>` dynamically and without blocking the thread

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I am trying to chain `Task<T>` objects in C# as done in JavaScript and without blocking the UI thread.

I see there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697167/use-an-async-callback-with-task-continuewith), but it uses the non-generic `Task` object as a return type of the process functions. I try to do the same with `Task<T>`.

I also see that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514375/chaining-two-functions-taska-and-a-taskb) is a closer question to my needs, but the accepted answer seems to use `.Result` twice, which I guess will block the UI thread. Also, note that I chain tasks dynamically, so I can't follow some easy workarounds. And also, the `Then` implementation given [here](http://ruudvanasseldonk.com/2013/05/01/the-task-monad-in-csharp) seems synchronous too (I am not sure if simply changing the `TaskContinuationOptions` on this old sample code will do what I want).

Here is what I have right now, but I can't even make it compile without blocking the thread:

```
    // Initial dummy task.
    private Task<bool> taskChain = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => true);

    // Chain dynamically on button click.
    private async void DoSth_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = ....;
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> del = async (t) => { return await ConvertAsync(data); };
        taskChain = taskChain.ContinueWith<bool>(() => del);
        var res = await taskChain;
    }
```

I have tried various different approaches, but I don't see how I can turn `Task<T>` to `Func<Task<T>, T>` that `ContinueWith<bool>()` seems to require (at least without doing some nasty UI thread blocking operation).

I would expect this to be easy, but I don't quite see the solution here... Isn't there a good and easy way to do this?

(Note: I guess I should probably call `Unwrap()` after the `ContinueWith()` but this seems like a detail at this point...)

Comment: What are the tasks that you want to chain? Are they the result of invoking async methods?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes, there are all async operations.

Comment: @Kalten While you *could* refactor the OP's code to not use `ContinueWith`, it would require the use of multiple methods, not one (or anonymous `async` methods, as the OP is kinda sorta trying to do), and I don't think it'd be cleaner.

Comment: @Kalten I can't call them the one after the other in hardcoded code, because the user chains the tasks dynamically, it's not in predetermined order.

Comment: u're just saying why other questions aren't answering your needs but dont explain what do you really need.
what is "but I can't even make it compile without blocking the thread", how is compiling has anything to do with runtime errors?

Comment: What happens if `ConvertAsync` returns false?

Comment: @YacoubMassad The that value is stored in `res`, just like if it returns `true`.  Subsequent code in the method can then do whatever it wants with that return value.

Comment: @OriRefael I basically needed to make it compile without making the code block the UI thread. That's all. I knew that using a few `.Result` would solve the compilation problem and chain the tasks, but it would also block the UI thread. Anyway, the question is answered now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UnWrap` is your friend here.  It'll allow you to have a continuation method that resolves to a `Task`, and then get a `Task` that represents that task before the continuation has even fired.

Also note that `FromResult` should be used to create an already completed task.

```
private Task<bool> taskChain = Task.FromResult(true);
private async void DoSth_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = CreateData();
    taskChain = taskChain.ContinueWith(t => ConvertAsync(data))
        .Unwrap();
    var res = await taskChain;
}
```

Note that I'd advise against doing this in-line in a click handler.  Create a class that is able to queue tasks, and then use *that*.  Of course, such a queue class is just following this same pattern:

```
public class TaskQueue
{
    private Task previous = Task.FromResult(false);
    private object key = new object();

    public Task<T> Enqueue<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskGenerator)
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            var next = previous.ContinueWith(t => taskGenerator()).Unwrap();
            previous = next;
            return next;
        }
    }
    public Task Enqueue(Func<Task> taskGenerator)
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            var next = previous.ContinueWith(t => taskGenerator()).Unwrap();
            previous = next;
            return next;
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow you to write:

```
private TaskQueue taskQueue = new TaskQueue();
private async void DoSth_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = CreateData();
    var res = await TaskQueue.Enqueue(ConvertAsync(data));
}
```

Now your mechanism of queuing tasks is separated from the business logic of what this click handler needs to do.

Comment: That was so easy that I feel embarrassed I haven't figure it out myself. I was obsessively using `ContinueWith<bool>()` instead... :( Thanks! :) And also thanks for the extra suggestions. :)

Comment: That `TaskQueue` class is well thought-through. Very good! Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to "chain" is to just `await`:

```
// Initial dummy task.
private Task taskChain = Task.FromResult(true);

// Chain dynamically on button click.
private async void DoSth_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var data = ....;
  taskChain = ChainedConvertAsync(taskChain, data);
  var res = await taskChain;
  ...
}

private async Task<Result> ChainedConvertAsync(Task precedent, Data data)
{
  await precedent;
  return await ConvertAsync(data);
}
```

On a side note, avoid `StartNew` and `ContinueWith`; they are dangerous APIs due to their default schedulers.

Comment: Oh... Right ! I can do that too! I haven't thought of that either! Can you suggest an article explaining in more detail why `ContinueWith` is dangerous? Is it because it changes the context? I guess it makes it safe if I use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` as you mention here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8767406/964053, right? Or there are still problems with Exception handling, etc?

Comment: @NoOne: It's the same reasons as [why `StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). More detail [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html). In summary: `ContinueWith` does not understand `async` delegates, has a bad default scheduler, and has non-optimal default continuation options.