# Creating a Task that represents a series of continuation tasks

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

For example let's say I'm writing a method with the below signature (C#4 so no async keywords):

```
public Task Refresh();
```

It will call one method (which also returns a `Task`) to perform the comms work, and then run a task continuation to update some internal state based on the retrieved data. e.g:

```
public Task Refresh()
{
    Task<MyData> commsTask = datasource.LoadData();
    Task handleDataTask = commsTask.ContinueWith( HandleNewData );

    return ?;
}
```

If I return the `handleDataTask` it's completion state correctly tracks the result of the 'Refresh' operation, but it doesn't correctly report it's started state.

I can wrap both in a new `Task.Factory.StartNew` and create them as child tasks, but it seems wasteful to spool up a new thread just for the sake of linking some task continuations.

Surely there is a neat efficient way to do this with the TPL?

Comment: Why do you care about the state?

Comment: So that the implementation matches the implicit documentation of the method signature? I don't know, ask the consumers of my method. There's probably 100s of possible uses for the `Task.Status` property, all I know is that my method should return a `Task` that correctly follows it's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, `Task.Status` is only used to find out about the **final state**. You can't rely on the task beeing `Started` anyway because that state might change any time.

Because of that fact it does not matter if the task you return has a "strange" state until it is completed. Only the three completed states (`Completed`, `Canceled`, `Faulted`) matter.

Comment: I agree with the 3 final states being important. But there is no guarantee the final task will run, so by returning your final task in the chain your risking that the 'Task' instance you return that represents the whole operation is perpetually stuck in `WaitingForActivation`. I didn't include it in the example, but it is possible for Task Continuations to not run if antecedent task's are cancelled.

Comment: @Tyson, if the antecedent task is canceled, the continuation task usually does run. If you use `TaskContinuationOptions` to modify that, the continuation is canceled too. Because of that, it won't be stuck in the `WaitingForActivation` state (unless the antecedent contains an infinite loop, or a deadlock).

Comment: @svick Hmm... I can't find the reference now, but I do remember seeing an example where a Task Continuation did not run. Although now I'm thinking although it didn't run, it still did transition straight into the `Cancelled` state as you say. I don't know, it still feels messy to return the final task to represent the whole sequence.

Comment: A task should be a total abstraction to how the result was computed. In that sense, this model is totally clean.

Answer (score 0):

I did some further research, and found a similar SO questions, and some blog posts:

[Task chaining without TaskCompletionSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884470/task-chaining-without-taskcompletionsource)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx

http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/05/20/eduasync-part-7-generated-code-from-a-simple-async-method.aspx

So there is a half answer - you can create a Task instance that represents all child Tasks without spooling up a new thread and attaching them as child tasks: Simply use a TaskCompletionSource. Simple example below applied to my question above without failure or cancellation handling:

```
public Task Refresh()
{
    var refreshTaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    Task<MyData> commsTask = datasource.LoadData();
    Task handleDataTask = commsTask.ContinueWith( HandleNewData );
    handleDataTask.ContinueWith( t => refreshTaskSource.SetResult(null) );

    return refreshTaskSource.Task;
}
```

**However** the Task returned by this method now transitions straight from `TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation` to `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion` (or Faulted/Cancelled if I had of handled those scenarios).